# Cutting a length of specific string with grep

Tags: grep

Let's say we have a string `"test123"` in a text file.
How do we cut out `"test12"` only or let's say there is other garbage behind `"test123"` such as `test123x19853` and we want to cut out `"test123x"`?

I tried with  `grep -a "test123.\{1,4\}" testasd.txt` and so on, but just can't get it right.
I also looked for example, but never found what I'm looking for.

Comment: `grep -o "test[0-9]\{1,4\}" testasd.txt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is `-o` which print out matched things only:

```
$ echo "test123x19853"|grep -o "test.\{1,4\}"
test123x

$ echo "test123x19853"|grep -oP "test.{1,4}"
test123x
```

> -o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN

Comment: @KL Sure thing :)

Answer (score 1):

expr:

```
kent$  x="test123x19853" 
kent$  echo $(expr "$x" : '\(test.\{1,4\}\)')
test123x
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with `awk`then try following(not this will look for continuous occurrences of alphabets and then continuous occurrences of digits, didn't limit it to 4 or 5).

```
echo "test123x19853" |  awk 'match($0,/[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```

In case you want to look for only 1 to 4  digits after 1st continuous occurrence of alphabets then try following(my `awk` is old version so using `--re-interval` you could remove it in case you have latest version of ittoo).

```
echo "test123x19853" | awk --re-interval 'match($0,/[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]{1,4}/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
```